# Why is my access.log file not accessible?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, log-files, files

I have an apache installation on my dev machine.  The httpd.conf is all set up right.  By the config file I should be getting an `access.log` file in my logs directory, but it doesn't seem to exist in the directory.

However if I search for the file in [AgentRansack](http://mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) it shows the file as existing and being some 400K in size.  I am running Windows 7 with Apache started manually as a process not a service.

I have:

- Set explorer to show system and hidden files
- Tried to open from AgentRansack directly but I get an error, or a blank file.
- Tried Shutting down apache to see if the files appear.

Why cant I access my access.log file?  Is this a know issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that if you have Apache installed to `%programfiles%` the problem lies with the way Windows handles files created by programs in the `%programfiles%` directory. In Vista and Windows 7, virtualization is used to save files to the `VirtualStore` directory (`%username%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`) when a program saves them to `%programfiles%`. This is relatively transparent to the program (Apache in this case), which means that monitoring its file access, shows that it is reading and writing from `%programfiles%`. (I once used SysInternals Process Monitor to try and track down my missing files - without any success - the only thing that worked was a full drive search).

Navigate to the correct path under VirtualStore (matching the path in Program Files) and you may find your missing file.

More information about VirtualStore is available on [Microsoft's site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'll check it out. You are correct its installed in program files (the default).